# mongoDB update query taking too long

Tags: mongodb, insert-update

We have a sharded cluster with 4 mongos, 3 config and two shards (each having 3 member replica-set). All mongo instances are on version 3.2.

We have a timely job running every 5 mins that upserts (insert if not present; and update if present) approximately 16K records in a collection currently having 150 million records. This collection is being maintained from past couple of years and each day new insertions are approx 20k.

Till last day (yesterday) this update process took only 30-35 seconds. But now it is observed that this update time is suddenly increased to roughly 110 seconds.

We have used following methods to track the cause but unable to find the root cause -

1. Config servers are in sync. (db.runCommand('dbhash') on config servers)
2. No other operations/jobs have been added/altered in this time window.
3. No replica-set or cluster configuration has been modified.
4. Balancer is taking and releasing lock as expected.
5. Target collection is almost equally distributed on both the shards (73 million on one and 77 million on other)
6. load average on all linux boxes is under 1.0.

We are stuck and not able to find the cause this sudden shoot-up in script time. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Insert and update code -

```
    //dataMap is a hashMap containing all parameters.
    UpdateOptions updateOptions = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);
    Document updateObject = new Document("$setOnInsert",new Document("cat", dataMap.get("cat"))
                            .append("$set", new Document("timeStamp",dataMap.get("timeStamp"))));
    Document query = new Document("host",dataMap.get("host"));                              
    query.append("timeStamp",dataMap.get(timeStamp));
    // collectionObject below is object of MongoCollection<Document>
    collectionObject.updateOne(query, updateObject, updateOptions);
```

Thanks and Regards,

Vibhav

PS - If anybody chooses to down-vote this question, please do mention reason in comments.

Comment: Can we see the insert/update code?

Comment: @Trey please find code above.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I do not see the cause, someone heavier in Mongo will have to take this one!